# background-size: cover causing background image to partially be hidden

Tags: html, image, css, background

I am trying to do a simple landing page, and I have an header, content div with a background image and a footer. I want it to be responsive, so in order to maintain size, I used `background-image:cover`. Now the problem is that on different screens, the image needs to zoom in so much that a part of it gets hidden, like this:

[image]

As you can notice, part of the text is cut. Any idea, please?

Comment: So, regardless of screen size or ratio, or image ratio, you want to display the whole image, undistorted? You can't do that. You either distort the image, or scale and hide as necessary.

Comment: That's what I thought, but could this be achieved in any way, including, say, making the image much larger at the bottom, so there is always a quite big hidden part and the text is still okay?

Comment: That's not how the `cover` background-size property works. As I said, you either trim the image proportionally, or distort it.

Comment: Which text is cut in this example? - if its the bit at the footer, surely this could just be put in the HTML instead of the image?

Comment: Under "Journey, we bring together".Okay, how do I put it into the html and not trim the image or distort it?

Comment: Ah i see it, just out of interest, have you tried using `background-size: contain ;` ? - you will probably end up with a border this way, but there may be a way to combat that too.

Comment: Why not put the text in as HTML code instead of embedding it in the background image?

Answer (score 1):

As BenM, says, you have to choose between

1) distorting the image

2) clipping it using cover

3) keep blank space on the sides using contains.

However, if your problem is mainly that the bottom of the image has to be always shown, you can set background-position-y: 100%;

This will ensure that the bottom of the image is always shown (but will cut more in the top ...)